# Help identifying organism

Tags: species-identification

I would like help identifying this "crab".

I looked through 32 pages of crabs on this resource http://species-identification.org/ but none of them look like this little animal found in the waters of Madeira.

They move fast and are something in between a spider and a crab.

[image: n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a crab - not anything spider. I originally thought it was a *Sally Lightfoot Crab* (a common crab on Madeira from the family of *shore crabs*) but I agree on your comment that it is more likely a **Nimble Spray Crab** (of the *Flat Crab* genus) as the specimen in your photo seemed a lot flatter than a shore crab (but I wasn't sure if it was just the shape of the rock).
The [Wikipedia article on this species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percnon_gibbesi) says that these are also referred to as another kind of Sally Lightfoot crab, and the fact that these are in a different taxonomic family from the other ones (the shore crabs) is a topic of debate.

[image]

They are observed in the coastal Atlantic and considered native to Madeira, but have recently spread into the Mediterranean

[image]

You can view a gallery of almost 200 photos of these crabs [on iNaturalist](https://inaturalist.org/taxa/61372-Percnon-gibbesi/browse_photos).

Comment: According to my dive instructor and to these pictures: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/61372-Percnon-gibbesi/browse_photos it indeed is a kind of Sally Lightfoot, specifically it's the Percnon Gibbesi (Spray Crab). Thanks. If you edit your answer to reflect this I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - edited to reflect your feedack